# why is my for loop not working in django views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Why is my for loop not working in django? i keep getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

```
@csrf_exempt
def testfunc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        for d,v in json_data.items():
            print(d)
        return JsonResponse(x,safe=False)
```

Comment: This means that the `.body` contains a JSON blob with list as outside item, so you enumerate over it with `for d in json_data`.

Answer (score 0):

The `json_data` is a list, since the outside item of the JSON blob in the `request.body` is a list, for example `["foo", "bar"]`, or `[{"key": "foo"}, {"key": "bar"}]`.

A list has no `.items()` method, so you enumerate over a list with:

```
json_data = json.loads(request.body)
for d in json_data:
    print(d)
```